# Sharing public folder between Ubuntu machines, via "Personal File Sharing"

Tags: gnome, samba, shared-folders

Launching Personal File Sharing from dash, the application opens with the message: "this feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system". I tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-user-share apache2.2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd` as per [this article](http://www.ubtutorials.com/tutorial/1012/use-ubuntus-public-folder-easily-share-files-between-computers), but that doesn't work (the error for that is: "apache2.2-bin : Breaks: gnome-user-share (< 3.8.0-2~) but 3.0.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
"). Is it possible to get this working on 14.04?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a lot of confusion about two different services, the one that Ubuntu calls Personal File Sharing is actually WebDav and it is controlled by Gnome-user-share package together with apache2.2-bin (webserver) and libapache2-mod-dnssd (avahi/mDNS/DNS-SD). The other one accessible from Nautilus folder share and property tab
For windows network shares you do not samba

Answer (score 1):

As far as my own experience tells me, you just have to:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-bin libapache2-mod-dnssd
```

Comment: Nope, it removes the personal file sharing application altogether. But then re-installing it (sudo apt-get install gnome-user-share) works and it is available again from dash, this time without the error message.

Comment: Ok, so it works. Did you have Samba installed before trying to do the above?

Comment: Yes, I think it came along with Ubuntu. Anyway, I'm not sure what's going on now after this installation: after I check "Share public files on network" after right clicking on the Public folder and navigating to the "Local Network Share" tab, sharing works. As I understand it this is the samba file sharing, and it works. But making changes on the "Personal File Sharing" application (e.g. requiring a password or disallowing the share) seem to take no effect. So I'm not sure whether the "Personal File Sharing" application really works (?).

Comment: I access into the shared Public folder from the other Ubuntu desktop via the `Browse Network` dialog of the file explorer, not the "Connect to Server" one by the way. As mentioned, it works (but seems to ignore settings in "Personal File Sharing"

Comment: My guess is, that you did not set up Samba completely as you had to install it somehow, it is not installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Try this: 0. install Samba via Software Center or command line
1. You have to add your user name to Samba, so:
sudo system-config-samba
2. Go to PREFERENCES/SAMBA USERS/ADD NEW SAMBA USER [not
a DIRECTORY]
3. I set it up like this
UNIX: (select one)
Windows Username: (select the same one)
Samba Password: choose one + confirm it

Comment: 4. The following might be unnecessary in your case as you already seem to have done it:
> Create shares via right click on the to be shared folder/sharing
options:
> + Share this folder: (select one)
> + Allow others to create and delete files in this folder 
> Create Share > Nautilus needs to add some permissions >
Add the permissions automatically > Close